# Expanding a Column of CSV Values in Spark Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, csv, apache-spark

Using Spark with Scala, I am writing a data extract. I have a Dataframe consisting of about a dozen columns, with values taken from existing databases. The final column is a string of comma-separated values. This final column can have a variable number of values. A simplified version of the data is below:

| Fizzbuzz | Flimflam | DingDong | CSVColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | lorem | 1,2,3 |
| b | 2 | ipsum | 4,5,6,7,8,9 |
| c | 3 | dolor | a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i |

In a text editor, the CSV appears like this (note the text qualifiers):

| csv |
| --- |
| a,1,lorem,"1,2,3" |
| b,2,ipsum,"4,5,6,7,8,9" |
| c,3,dolor,"a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i" |

This dataframe is meant to be the input for a parser written separately. This parser uses a CSVReader to parse each line as a string array. As such, it does not function properly when the last column is its own column. ArrayOutOfBounds exceptions are the result.

If I manually open the CSV in a text editor and remove the text qualifiers for the CSVColumn, I can parse the Dataframe successfully. This is not a solution, however, and so I was wondering if there is any programmatic way to accomplish this.

What would be ideal is a Dataframe that ends up outputting like this:

| Fizzbuzz | Flimflam | DingDong | CSV1 | CSV2 | CSV3 | CSV4 | CSV5 | CSV6 | CSV7 | CSV8 | CSV9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | lorem | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| b | 2 | ipsum | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |  |  |  |
| c | 3 | dolor | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i |

Such that its CSVs look like this, without text qualifiers:

| csv |
| --- |
| a,1,lorem,1,2,3 |
| b,2,ipsum,4,5,6,7,8,9 |
| c,3,dolor,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i |

Essentially, if given a column of CSV's in a Dataframe, is it possible to expand the Dataframe horizontally when splitting the column?

Since the length of the CSV may vary, I can't just use withColumn() calls to add the necessary columns. If I can find an upper limit to how many columns are needed, I may be able to add that many, but such an approach is likely to be very messy.

I am hoping a better solution exists. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` already contains CSVColumn as array, just calculate max array length in the first pass:

```
val maxLength = df.agg(max(size($"CSVColumn"))).as[Int].head
9
```

Then dynamically generate that many columns:

```
(1 to maxLength).foldLeft(df) {
  (acc, i) => acc.withColumn(s"CSV$i", element_at($"CSVColumn", i))
}.show()
+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|Fizzbuzz|Flimflam|DingDong|           CSVColumn|CSV1|CSV2|CSV3|CSV4|CSV5|CSV6|CSV7|CSV8|CSV9|
+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|       a|       1|   lorem|           [1, 2, 3]|   1|   2|   3|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|       b|       2|   ipsum|  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]|   4|   5|   6|   7|   8|   9|null|null|null|
|       c|       3|   dolor|[a, b, c, d, e, f...|   a|   b|   c|   d|   e|   f|   g|   h|   i|
+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```